# Closed families of random variables exists?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, closed-graph

If $\psi$ and $\nu$ are real random variables with normal distribution, their sum is also normal. Do we have such families on a half line or, more importantly on $[a,b]$? (I.e., the value of the random variables should be in [a,b].) We do not want addition to take us out of the family.

Comment: In particular, can we have $\mu$ and $\nu$ to be independent, and have distribution on [0,1] to be $f(x)$, such that the distritution of $\mu+\nu$ is simply $f(x/2   ) 2$, with $x\in[0,2]$?

Comment: You left out an important word: The sum of two _independent_ normal variables is normal.

Answer (score 0):

On the half line there is always the [gamma family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution): the sum of independent Gamma($a$,1) and Gamma($b$,1) random variables is Gamma($a+b$,1)-distributed.